# Spring Data JPA order by value from OneToMany relation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I am trying to sort a result by nested collection element value. I have a very simple model:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Setting> settings = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Setting {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private User user;

    private String key;
    private String value;

    // getters and setters
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {
}
```

I want to have a result returned sorted by the value of one setting.
Is it possible to order by user.settings.value where settings.name = 'SampleName' using Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL?

Answer (score 0):

I've used `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. let's see `findAll` for example.

```
Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

Before call this method you can create your specification dynamically (where condition) and `Pageable` object with dynamic `Sort` information.

For example

```
...

Specification<T> whereSpecifications = Specification.where(yourWhereSpeficiation);
Sort sortByProperty = Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("property"));
PageRequest orderedPageRequest = PageRequest.of(1, 100, sortByProperty);

userRepository.findAll(whereSpecifications, PageRequest.of(page, limit, orderedPageRequest));
```

Comment: But it is not always a case I want to sort by this field - sometimes it is another field

Comment: But how to create a sortByProperty to sort by user.setting.name?

Comment: Sort.Order.asc("setting.name")